# which branch is specified in these git push commands

Tags: branch, local, git-push, remote-branch

what is the difference between :

```
git push origin HEAD: <name-of-remote-branch> 
git push origin CURRENT_BRANCH_NAME
```

Is CURRENT_BRANCH_NAME the name of my **local** branch or the **remote** branch ?

Answer (score 0):

From `git help push`:

> The format of a <refspec> ... [is] the source object <src>, followed by a colon :, followed by the destination ref <dst>.

Then:

> missing :<dst> means to update the same ref as the <src>

i.e. `git` will interpret `git push origin CURRENT_BRANCH_NAME` as `git push origin CURRENT_BRANCH_NAME:CURRENT_BRANCH_NAME`, assuming your git config is relatively standard.